# Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, adapter, ibm-data-studio

I am getting below error when calling stored procedure written in IBM DB2 from my Worklight SQLAdapter

Invocation Result of procedure: 'track_ReqByMob_No' from the Worklight Server:

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: Failed to retrieve data with procedure : track_ReqByMob_No"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

Console output

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project Raoming_Advisor]SQLAdapter/StoredProcedureFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project Raoming_Advisor]


Failed to retrieve data with procedure : track_ReqByMob_No

FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project Raoming_Advisor]com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException:

DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=TRACK_REQBYMOB_NO;PROCEDURE,

DRIVER=3.66.46java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to retrieve data with procedure : track_ReqByMob_No
```

My Stored Procedure in DB2(TRAVEL is my schema name, trouble_ticket is my table name

```
CREATE PROCEDURE track_ReqByMob_No (IN MOB_NO BIGINT )
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

P1: BEGIN

DECLARE cursor2 CURSOR WITH RETURN for

SELECT TRAVEL ."trouble_ticket"."id", TRAVEL."trouble_ticket"."query_trouble_ticket",TRAVEL."trouble_ticket"."status_trouble_ticket"    FROM TRAVEL."trouble_ticket" WHERE TRAVEL."trouble_ticket"."Mob_No"=MOB_NO;

        OPEN cursor2;
END P1
```

My SQLadapter calling function

```
function  track_ReqByMob_No(Mob_No){
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
        procedure : "track_ReqByMob_No",
        parameters : [Mob_No]
    });
}
```

Comment: Solution: Used Schema name in my calling SQLadapter function function track_ReqByMob_No(Mob_No){ return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({ procedure : "TRAVEL.track_ReqByMob_No", parameters : [Mob_No] }); }

Comment: Can you please add the solution below so others can see it more easily

Comment: minimum reputation 10 is required to add the soultion ; thats the reason i have added solution in comment

Comment: You should be good now to add the solution. You have 11 Reputation

Comment: Not a problem. You can also mark your answer below as accepted if you think it fulfills your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used Schema name in calling function for e.g. my schema name is TRAVEL so in my SQLadapter calling function

instead of ***procedure : "track_ReqByMob_No" ***

i will write  *** procedure : "TRAVEL.track_ReqByMob_No"***

----------my UPADTED SQLadapter calling function----------

```
function  track_ReqByMob_No(Mob_No){
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
        procedure : "TRAVEL.track_ReqByMob_No",
        parameters : [Mob_No]
    });
}
```